# How to get the Id of the row that contains a specific string SQL PyODBC

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am trying to get the id of the table row that contains a specific string, in my case a username.

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username = ?", user)
myresult = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.commit()
rez = myresult[-1][0]
```

I am getting this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JDLu.png)

The result of the query [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fi9Y.png)

Error after using rez=cursor.fetchval()
[image]

Comment: Immediately after the `.execute()` try `rez = cursor.fetchval()`

Comment: Additional notes: Post error messages, etc., as text, not as screenshots. See [ask] for more tips on asking good questions.

Comment: I am getting another error now, check the edited post in a sec

Comment: `.fetchval()` returns `None` if the SELECT query returns no rows. You need to check for that before trying to INSERT that value into the `id_user` column of the other table.